# mysqldump: dump several tables from db. what will be locked?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have active database with dozens of tables. Among them several are unused (no queries/insertions are performing over them for a while).
I want to dump that inactive tables. I would suggest that it will be harmless to use `mysqldump -u.. -h.. -p... mydb tbl1 tbl2 > dump.sql` and nothing except that tables will be locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current way you are doing it

```
mysqldump -u.. -h.. -p... mydb tbl1 tbl2
```

each table is locked during the SELECT phase in a specific way

Note the effects during the dump

- Each table that is MyISAM should allow SELECTs but block INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs
- While dumping tbl1, tbl2 is fully accessible
- While dumping tbl2, tbl1 is fully accessible

If those tables (tbl1 and tbl2) are inactive, then such a dump would be harmless to busy tables.